# Can I get the current controller object from ApplicationController in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is there any way I can get the controller that's about to handle the request from ApplicationController class?

Basically I'm trying to figure out a way of returning to HTTP when HTTPS is no longer required. I have configured Devise to use SSl as instructed:

```
#in config/environments/production.rb
config.to_prepare { Devise::SessionsController.force_ssl }
config.to_prepare { Devise::RegistrationsController.force_ssl }
```

However, once a Devise controller redirects to SSL it stayed there. There was a code snippet in the Devise wiki that redirects back to HTTP once a Devise action is completed. However, that won't work if user navigates away using any other means.

From my .NET way of thinking perhaps I can do something in the base class of all controllers, i.e. ApplicationController. If I can have an array of controller class names that require SSL, then redirects to HTTP if the current controller class does not require it, perhaps that will be a sufficient crude solution for now? I am a Ruby and Rails newbie so I may not be looking at this the right way at all...

Thanks,
Dany.

Comment: Do you have an example what to solve? I don't understand why you need that.

Comment: I have edited my question to further elaborate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the current controller name in the `params` hash: `params[:controller]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run `controller_name`

```
[3] pry(#<PostsController>)> controller_name
=> "posts"
```